# display content from specific div on print

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to print some content from firefox. I already have inside html page `<div id="printContent"></div>` which is hidden by default. Using css I display this div with injected content  on printing like

```
@media print {    
    #printContent{
        display:block;
    }
}
```

but on print preview I'm getting some other page div, not just this `#printContent`. What should I do to get only `#printContent` on firefox print preview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hide the other content using display:none in media selector - I'd suggest your #printContent div be a child of body, then you can

```
@media print {    
    body>* {
        display:none !important;
    }
    body>div#printContent{
        display:block !important;
    }
}
```

edit: added !important - depending on other CSS you may or may not need `!important`